# matlab oop "use data of hole class" for calculation

Tags: matlab, oop

First, sorry for the bad title - I'm new to OO programming - basically I'd like to understand how Matlab works with oop classes.

Before I ask my question, here is a basic example of what I want to do:

I have two houses and some data about them and I got the idea, to work with oop classes. Here is my .m file.

```
classdef building
  properties
  hohe = 0;
  lange = 0;
  breite = 0;
  xabstandsolar = 0;
  yabstandsolar = 0;
end

methods
  function obj = building(hohe, lange, breite, xabstandsolar, yabstandsolar)
    obj.hohe = hohe;
    obj.lange = lange;
    obj.breite = breite;
    obj.xabstandsolar = xabstandsolar;
    obj.yabstandsolar = yabstandsolar;
   end

   function hohenwinkel(h)
     h = h
     d = sqrt(obj.xabstandsolar^2 + yabstandsolar^2);
     gamma_v = atand((obj.hohe - h)/(d));
   end 
  end
end
```

I filled it with some data - for example

```
>>H1 = building(10,8,6,14,8)
>>H2 = building(18,8,6,14,0)
```

And now I want to calculate "gamma_v" (as an 1x2 array) for each building. Any ideas, how I can archive this?

Edit:
 I want to create gamma_v (as an array) automatically for all objects in the class "building". There will be a lot more "houses" in the final script.

Comment: You should be creating an array of `building` objects (`H(1), H(2), ..., H(n)`), not individual variables. You can then loop through these to perform the necessary operation(s).

Comment: Gosh, I found a solution. Thanks for your tipp with H(n) - that helped me a lot! Maybe you add this comment in your answer, so I can mark it as solved.

Comment: My comment is no different than @Suever's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `hohenwinkel` method needs to accept *two* input arguments. The first argument for non-static methods is always the object itself (unlike C++, you'll have to explicitly list it as an input argument) and the second input will be your `h` variable. You'll also want to actually return the `gamma_v` value using an output argument for your method.

```
function gamma_v = hohenwinkel(obj, h)
    d = sqrt(obj.xabstandsolar^2 + obj.yabstandsolar^2);
    gamma_v = atand((obj.hohe - h)/(d));
end
```

Then you can invoke this method on each building to get the value

```
gamma_v1 = hohenwinkel(H1);
gamma_v2 = hohenwinkel(H2);
```

If you want to have an array of buildings, you can create that array

```
houses = [building(10,8,6,14,8), building(18,8,6,14,0)];
gamma_v = hohenwinkel(houses);
```

and then construct your `hohenwinkel` function to operate on each one and return the result

```
function gamma_v = hohenwinkel(obj, h)

    if numel(obj) > 1
        % Compute hohenwinkel for each one
        gamma_v = arrayfun(@(x)hohenwinkel(x, h), obj);
        return
    end

    d = sqrt(obj.xabstandsolar^2 + obj.yabstandsolar^2);
    gamma_v = atand((obj.hohe - h)/(d));
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That isnt exactly the solution I was looking for. I want to create gamma_v (as an array) automatically for all objects in the class "building". There will be a lot more "houses" in the final script.

Comment: @Sunsheep Updated with a way to deal with that

Comment: Thanks again for your effort! But now I get an error message:
warning: struct: converting a classdef object into a struct overrides theaccess restrictions defined for properties. All properties are returned, including private and protected ones.
warning: called from
    Verschattung at line 89 column 8
warning: struct: converting a classdef object into a struct overrides theaccess restrictions defined for properties. All properties are returned, including private and protected ones.

Comment: @Sunsheep That is because you must be calling `struct(obj)` at some point. Also it is a warning and not an error so if you *need* to do it, it's fine

Answer (score 0):

there is some tricky solution (and its not recommended)(@Suever solution is better)
 you should create a handle class

```
 classdef gvclass<handle 
       properties 
            gvarr=[];
       end 
       methods 
            function setgvarr(obj,value)
                  obj.gvarr=[obj.gvarr,value];
             end
       end
  end
```

then use this class in your building class

```
classdef building<handle 
properties
  gv
  hohe = 0;
  lange = 0;
  breite = 0;
  xabstandsolar = 0;
  yabstandsolar = 0;
end

methods
  function obj = building(hohe, lange, breite, xabstandsolar, yabstandsolar,handle_of_your_gv_class,h)
    obj.hohe = hohe;
    obj.lange = lange;
    obj.breite = breite;
    obj.xabstandsolar = xabstandsolar;
    obj.yabstandsolar = yabstandsolar;
    obj.gv=handle_of_your_gv_class;
    obj.hohenwinkel(h);
   end

   function hohenwinkel(obj,h)

     d = sqrt(obj.xabstandsolar^2 + yabstandsolar^2);
     gamma_v = atand((obj.hohe - h)/(d));
     obj.gv.setgvarr(gamma_v);
   end 
  end
end
```

finally before creating any building you should create an object of gv class and pass it to the building constructor,

```
Egv=gvclass();
H1 = building(10,8,6,14,8,Egv,2)
H2 = building(18,8,6,14,0,Egv,3)
```

and to access gv array:

```
 Egv.gvarr
```

you should do more effort on this issue to debug possible errors.